# Problem with the synchronization between QField and QGIS

Tags: qgis, qfield

I have a serious issue with synchronizing QField and QGIS. I'm working with .qgs project that I export to QField via QFieldSync, then I added a new feature and every thing works perfectly even when I synchronize with QGIS I can see my new feature, but when I want to edit the feature that I've recently created (change the value of a field) the synchronization with QGIS doesn't seem to be working, it preserves the old values.

If you have any idea about what is happening tell me please.

Comment: I know this post is old but did you manage to solve this problem? I am having the same issues.